# Can ESD from a person damage circuitry even though it was not perceivable?

Tags: esd

I know that when working with circuits it is important to avoid ESD onto sensitive components.  But I am wondering when I inevitably make the mistake of discharging static onto a PCB will I know?  Like the typical sensation of being shocked. Are there ESDs from humans to circuitry that are too small to perceive by the human, but still damaging to the circuit?

Comment: Most definitely you can damage components without knowing. a 1.8V part could be damaged by 10V, and by the time you can feel an ESD shock it is at least 3000V.

Comment: I'm always shocked (ugh, pun initially unintended) by how easy ***and*** difficult it is to damage electronics via ESD.  I've always been careful regarding ESD and take appropriate steps such as wearing a grounded ESD strap when working on electronics.  One day, while performing an installation, another person on the project showed up with, literally, a backpack filled with circuit boards. The boards weren't in anti-static bags or anything.  They took absolutely no precautions whatsoever.  I was surprised that every component they brought worked, but truth be told, they all did.  Surprised me.

Comment: Maybe this short story demonstrates how sensitive today's devices are: About 35 years ago a friend of mine had built some electronic circuit using a "555" timer chip, and he did not connect the inputs that he didn't want to use. The effect was when we got closer that about 20cm with the hand, the circuit reacted. Compared to today's structure sizes and operating voltages such "555" timer was quite insensitive I guess. As others pointed out, ESD does not mean it completely destroys the circuit, but it can damage it to make it unreliable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is ***very*** easy to damage a circuit with ESD ***WITHOUT EVER DISCHARGING ANYTHING***.

A simple experiment demonstrates this.

1. Wash your hair and let it dry.
2. Blow up a balloon.
3. Rub the balloon against some fur (or your own hair, but the purpose is to show that you can transfer static charges without touching the thing that holds static.
4. Once you have charged the balloon on the fur, stand in front of a mirror and slowly bring the balloon towards your dry hair.
5. You will see your hair attracted towards the charged balloon. The charge holder (balloon) has ***induced*** an opposite static charge into the hair ***simply by being near*** to the hair.

If you -- or anything with a static charge -- comes 'near' another object that is even partially conductive, an opposite charge will be induced in that object. Whether or not that induced charge can damage the device depends on the induced voltage and how much energy is contained in the combined induced charge and voltage.

For TTL circuits this was not usually a problem.

For CMOS circuits in their 12v and 5v incarnations, this induced charge was not typically a problem. Usually direct contact was required for a damaging discharge.

***For 3.3 volt, and lower voltage devices, however, this induced charge can and sometimes does damage devices without you ever needing to touch the device.  The charge induced on any part of the device will further induce charges on parts near to that and so on in cascades that can be well removed from any part of the device "near" the original induced charge.  If the induced charge at any of those locations exceeds the insulation around that location -- air gap, semiconductor material, etc. -- electricity will flow. If the charge is sufficiently energetic, it will damage something.***

To prevent this --

1. Wear a static wrist strap, ***AND***
2. Make sure that wrist strap is correctly attached to a static-suppressing work area, e.g. an anti-static mat on your table, ***AND***
3. Make sure the anti-static mat is correctly grounded to the building/work-area ground, ***AND***
4. Make sure the device ground -- and device power if device is not operating -- is ALSO attached to that anti-static mat, ***AND***
5. Use chairs and wear clothing that minimize generation of static, ***AND***
6. ***REQUIRE*** anyone who approaches to **ALSO** put on a static wrist strap and attach to the same anti-static mat ***BEFORE*** letting them anywhere near the device(s).

This might seem like overkill.  And for inexpensive parts or equipment it probably is.  BUT the first time you fry a multi-thousand-dollar piece of equipment without knowing why, it will in hindsight not seem like overkill after all.

You can -- ***in an emergency DO NOT DO THIS AT HOME*** I am a registered Professional Engineer who works with electricity and electronics and even ***I*** try to never use this method -- put down aluminum foil on your desk, and use an alligator-clip to connect the foil to the ground in an outlet -- ***VERY HAZARDOUS AND LIKELY TO GET YOU KILLED IF YOU DON'T KNOW EXACTLY WHAT YOU ARE DOING*** -- and then always make sure you are touching the foil and that you also attach an alligator clip from the foil to a common ground on the electronics.

Other examples of static transfer with no contact:

1. Bend water -- https://www.wikihow.com/Bend-Water-with-Static-Electricity
2. Static induction -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction
3. Pick up things without touching them -- https://www.msichicago.org/science-at-home/hands-on-science/static-cling/

Comment: The easiest electrostatic discharge I've experienced is pulling off a fleece blanket from a leather chair or sofa. You *hear* the discharge.

Comment: This is also extremely important for plain MOSFETs. Especially if working with a really fancy state-of-the-art SiC FET that cost you hundreds of dollars for a single one. (Fortunately, I don't know this from experience, I know this from being incredibly stressed while working with such a FET but fortunately it turned out fine!)

Comment: At least put a 1 or 10MOhm resistor in series with the foil and ground clip.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, very definitely. It is insidious b/c the damage by ESD may not always cause outright failure of the component or system. It may result in degraded performance.

Comment: _"Is ESD from a person onto circuitry always perceivable?"_ - _"Yes"_, and then the rest of your answer goes on to say _"No"_.

Comment: @pipe Well, the question suffers from the fact that it contains two equivalent questions, one of which is negated.

Comment: Your answer is unclear, particularly the first statement. While the reason it's unclear is that the question asks both "Is ESD from a person onto circuitry always perceivable?" in the title and the effective opposite "Are there ESDs from humans to circuitry that are too small to perceive by the human, but still damaging to the circuit?" in the question body, it is, ultimately, your responsibility to make your answer clear. Please [edit] to clarify. Basically, the way the question is worded, you can't just give a bare "yes" or "no" answer and have what you mean be clear.

Comment: I'll expand on my previous answer with some specific examples. EXAMPLE #1: The current gain of a transistor (called "beta" or "hfe" on data sheets) can be degraded..

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes you can feel the electrostatic discharge from your body to the circuit/component but this might not always be an indication of damage. Or, you can't even feel anything but can't understand that the circuit/component is damaged until you powered it.

---

An interesting experience I had: A few years ago, I had designed an LCD monitor control board for a customer. Once we got sample PCBs and the components, I just wanted to assemble a circuit to see if/how it works. I wore my ESD strap, assembled the circuit, powered the board and it worked. Then I wanted to mount the board in its prototype case. I removed my ESD strap, took the board at hand, stood up, and walked to the next desk. While I was holding the board, one of the employees saw it and said "oooh looking nice" and wanted to take the board in hand. He touched my hand before taking the board. I felt a "little" ESD, so didn't pay attention. Then I mounted the board but it was not working. Most likely the ESD from him to my hand had killed the circuit.

---

I personally recommend this video about ESD (from famous Linus with help of Electro BOOM):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXkgbmr3dRA

Answer (score 3):

How ESD damage works:

Depending on surroundings the capacitance of a human body is like 100-500pF

It is pretty easy to build a 5 .. 50kV potential difference between your body and ground or other object and then see a shiny spark 1..3cm or more when approaching a grounded object. It may as well be somewhat painful.

On the other hand, if your very own voltage is, say, 50-200V, you will neither see, nor hear, nor see the spark. But there still will be a small spark.

Now, imagine you have an unprotected MOS gate with 10pF capacitance that has an absolute maximum rating of 20V. You touch it. Your voltage is lowered by the added capacitance and instead of 100V you are now like 90V from the ground. So is the unfortunate MOS gate. You feel nothing and the gate is gone.